# how to get current MKZoomScale for mapView

Tags: ios

I am trying to get the current zoomScale for mapview. I was using

zoomScale = self.mapView.bounds.size.width/ self.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;

But the zoomScale does not equal to the one passed to

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
        zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
        inContext:(CGContextRef)context

if i use   zoomScale = 2*self.mapView.bounds.size.width/ self.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width,  it can euqal to the one in drawMapRect method on retina iphone but not for any ipad.

So I am still not sure how to get the correct zoomScale for any device, the zoomScale should match the one n drawMapRect.

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you DO get the zoom scale. Maps are scaled by the map region, which is type MKCoordinateRegion.

Comment: how to get the zoomScale, as the one passed to drawMapRect in overlay view.